# How to add background music to video in html5?

Tags: javascript, html

I already have video being played with its own audio. I want to add some background music to existing video. How can I achieve that in HTML5 and javascript?

Should I mix the video and audio data bits and play using one video element `<video></video>`?

Or

Should I play the video and audio with its own `<video></video> and <audio></audio>` tags?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mixing would be better, or else user (browser) must download the both music and video file before playing it. Requires longer time to load the media.

Comment: How to mix audio and video in javascript? @FrozenFire

Comment: @Vikram Babu Nagineni You need to use media editing software.

Answer (score 1):

You should mix audio and your existing video with a video editor (iMovie, Adobe Premiere etc) and after that add video to your website using `<video></video>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is two cases:

- If the audio you want to add is triggered by a user action, you should add it on a separate audio tag.
- Otherwise, like background music, you should add the audio track to the video one, it will save bandwidth.